# Найти все совпадения в сплошной строке по заранее заданному шаблону

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Наткнулся на задачу в codewars и погряз в ней прочно. 
[Условие](https://www.codewars.com/kata/new-cashier-does-not-know-about-space-or-shift/train/javascript)

Вот что мне удалось наработать:

```js
function getOrder(input) {
  let result = [];
  let orderList = [
    "Burger",
    "Fries",
    "Chicken",
    "Pizza",
    "Sandwich",
    "Milkshake",
    "Coke"
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < orderList.length; i++) {
    let regExp = RegExp(orderList[i], "i",);
    let sortedStrs = input.match(regExp).join("  ");
    result.push(sortedStrs.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sortedStrs.slice(1));
  }
  result = result.join(' ')
  return result;
}
console.log(
  getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza")
);
```

Конкретно в данном случае, мой скрипт находит лишь раз совпадение, остальные отбрасывает, как не нужные, хотя так быть не должно.
Ответ должен быть:
"Burger Fries Chicken Pizza Pizza Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Milkshake Coke"
Добавлял квантификаторы глобального поиска - тот же результат. Где мой просчет?

Comment: `let orderList = ...; return orderList.filter(item => input.includes(item.toLowerCase())).join(' ');`

Comment: Ваше решение находит лишь одно совпадение.
expected 'Burger Fries Chicken Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Coke' to equal 'Burger Fries Chicken Pizza Pizza Pizza Sandwich Milkshake Milkshake Coke'

Comment: А, да, не обратил внимание, что повторяющиеся значения должны повторяться и в ответе

Comment: Тогда немного поизвращённее: `return orderList.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(new Array(input.split(item.toLowerCase()).length - 1).fill(item)), []).join(' ');`

Comment: Вообще не пойму, что автор задачи намудрил. Решение вроде удовлетворяет условию, простые тесты проходит, но в итоге при попытке запустить в оболочке codewars выдает ошибки, равно как и с моим решением. Это уже малость раздражает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли `Onionrings`:

```js
function getOrder(input) {
  let m, result=[], orderList = [
    "Burger", "Fries", "Chicken", "Pizza", "Sandwich", "Onionrings", "Milkshake", "Coke"
  ];
  for (var el of orderList) {
    let r = new RegExp(el, "gi");
    while (m=r.exec(input)) {
      result.push(m[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + m[0].substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
   }
  return result.join(" ");
}

console.log(  getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza")
);
```

Тест пройден:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как получилось самостоятельно родить ответ.

```js
function getOrder(input) {
  let result = [];
  let orderList = [
    "Burger",
    "Fries",
    "Chicken",
    "Pizza",
    "Sandwich",
    "Milkshake",
    "Coke"
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < orderList.length; i++) {
    let regExp = RegExp(orderList[i], "gi");
    let sortedStrs = input.match(regExp).join(" ");
    result.push(
      sortedStrs
        .split(/\s+/)
        .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
        .join(" ")
    );
  }
  return result.join(" ");
}
console.log(
  getOrder("milkshakepizzachickenfriescokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza")
);
```

Тесты проходит, однако внутренний валидатор codewars ругается.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null.
Что с ним делать пока ума не приложу.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'join' of null" тут может возникнуть, если во входной строке отсутствует какая-либо из искомых строк из `orderList`, например, попробуйте `getOrder("milkshakepizzacokeburgerpizzasandwichmilkshakepizza")`